# Create difference chart using MSChart

Tags: c#, mschart, difference

I have 2 series and I want to plot also the difference between them, positive values with red, negative colors with green. I want to obtain the same effect as using in Java from org.jfree.chart
`new XYDifferenceRenderer(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, false)`
Is that possible using MSChart?
Below is what I want to obtain

[image]

Comment: Maybe a [StackedArea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449426/how-to-create-area-range-chart/25453274?s=1|0.0775#25453274) chart?

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Hey if you found the link useful could be the 1st one to upvote it ;-)