# How to create charts for integrals

Tags: c#, .net, charts

Im writing scientific/educational app. One of the features is calculating integrals aproximation with rectangle and trapeze methods. I want to display f(x) function chart with the results of the calculations where i could mark the areas that are accurate and inaccurate with different colors.

[image: Rectangle method]

[image: Trapeze method]

So far, i tried to use charts from DataVisualisation.Charting. For displaying f(x) functions i used Spline chart. In case of rectangle method i tried to use bar chart for aproximation.

There are two problems: firstly, the mesureing point are in the middle of the bars instead of on the right side; secondly, i don't know if it's possible to mark the inacuracies like on the pics above while useing the default library.

[image: rectangle method result]

Comment: I strongly advise againt using the Bar or Column charttype for this or any kind of geometric purpose. It is next to impossible to calculate all the necessary numbers for the bars. You can use a variation of area charts.

Comment: @TaW Area charts are exactly what i was looking for  for the trapeze method! Thanks.

Comment: @Taw The problem is, how i can make an area chart look like a bar chart?

Comment: You probably mean columns (vertical) not bars (horizontal), right? - The trick is to add not just one datapoint but enough to decribe the area needed. Best write a function that takes the needed value and adds as many points as needed for the area. Are you looking for rectangles or triangles?

Comment: Yeah, i ment columns, sorry. I would have to test it out, because i don't know how it will behave if on the same x position there would be multiple y positions. 
About the shapes, im useing two different methods to calculate the surface below the f(x) function. One is uesing rectangles, the other, trapezes. It's only to show the differences in the efectivenes and precision between those two.

Comment: wait... i could theoretically add each collumn as another series. That way there wouldn't be an issue with multiple y values on the same  x value

Comment: All areas will start from the bottom of the chart. a function to add one can be as simple as this `void addColumnArea(Series s, int x1, int x2, int y, Color c )
{
    int pt1 = s.Points.AddXY(x1, 0);
    int pt2 = s.Points.AddXY(x1, y);
    int pt3 = s.Points.AddXY(x2, y);
    int pt4 = s.Points.AddXY(x2, 0);
    s.Points[pt3].Color = c;
}` - But all areas start at the bottom; to avoid that one would need a stackedarea. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449426/how-to-create-area-range-chart/25453274#25453274) is an example.. -

Comment: If you don't need full serialization you may actually have an easier time drawing the shapes in, say, the PostPaint event. You would need to values for the points of the polygons and convert them to pixels with the axis conversion functions. Quite easy actually. You just need to decide where you want to put the values. Are the 'trapezes' you mention visible in your images?

Comment: in case of trapeze method, the result supposed to be like on the second pic. For now ill try to do it with the the function that You suggested. Thanks for Your help :)

Comment: OK, the function can easily be expanded to take two y values and create a column with a slanted top.